# Data source name not found and no default driver specified while reading MDB file in linux using java

Tags: java, weblogic

I have a simple program which reads an `.MDB` file. the program is a web application which is deployed on `linux`, a `Welbogic` server.  When i run the code i am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3073)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at javaschedular.TheJob.getConnection(TheJob.java:52)
    at javaschedular.TheJob.execute(TheJob.java:28)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

When i run the same code on my windows desktop it runs just fine. 
Following is the code that i am using to connect to `.MDB` file:

```
private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url2 =
        "jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=/home/oracle/Desktop/DS/1037.MDB";
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url2, username, password);

}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. `Class.forName(driver);` doesn't do anything... I'm not sure why you're doing it. What are the details/settings of your unixODBC in weblogic?

Comment: the code which is creating is problem is in the snipit. have any solutions ???